# Soap UI startup parameters

Tags: command-line-arguments, soapui

I have the free version of Soap UI and several different workspaces. I would like to set up several shortcuts to Soap UI with each shortcut including a start-up parameter indicating which workspace to load, but I can't find what the actual parameters are to do that. I looked over the documentation, and I saw a reference to the fact that there are start-up parameters available, but I couldn't find where they were listed.

Is there a way to do this (similar to eclipse's "-data" parameter)?

thanks.

Comment: Has anyone found a list of start-up parameters for `SoapUI-<ver>.exe`?  I am inclined to ask a separate question to find as much (being that this question and the accepted answer are really workspace focused despite the question's title) but figured I would check with a follow-up comment first.

Comment: Following @kiprainy's advice below, I checked the SoapUI source, specifically `SoupUI.java`.  According to `initSoapUIOptions()`, `SoapUI-<ver>.exe` command-line options include `w` (`"Specified the name of the workspace xml file"`) as @kiprainy describes and `p` (`"Sets project name and its password in format <project name>:<password>"`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily by creating a workspace file that references your project, and then starting soapui from the command line or a batch file. The switch you need to specify a workspace file is -w.

```
soapui-4.5.1 -w "c:\path to my workspace file"
```

All your workspace file needs, in turn, is a single node with your project name and the path to your project file.

```
<con:soapui-workspace xmlns:con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config" soapui-version="4.5.1" name="Projects"> <con:description/> <con:settings/> <con:project name="My Project Name">D:/path to my project.xml</con:project> </con:soapui-workspace>
```

I know this is old, but I had the same question, and was frustrated that I couldn't specify a startup project. I downloaded the SoapUI source code, and dug around until I found the answer.

Comment: Thank you! This works great. For myself, I didn't have to modify the workspace file (but I'm only interested in starting up with a specific workspace, not so worried about the project).

Comment: My pleasure. Now if I could only figure out how to do the same thing with LoadUI.

Comment: I use testrunner.bat.  Why do you choose here to not run with that method?

Comment: The method that I've suggested was the easiest way I found to specify a workspace file and startup project. If you're using a batch file, you could easily include the paramater in there as well.

Comment: Very cool.  How did you learn of the `-w` command-line option?  Do you know of a list of command-line options for `SoapUI-<ver>.exe`?

Comment: @J0e3gan I had to download the source code and poke around to find the command line options. I wasn't able to find documentation anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I didn't think of that option.  It's unfortunate that command-line options for `SoapUI-<ver>.exe` are not documented like those for `testrunner.bat` (which are documented very well), but examining the `SoapUI-<ver>.exe` source will work.

Comment: A +1 to you, good sir, simply for downloading the SoapUI code and going through it to find the solution.

Comment: By the way, you didn't happen to notice a switch for specifying a global settings file path, did you? I'd even settle for a switch that allows me to override the user's home directory for SoapUI. [I found a way via the installed batch files](http://forum.loadui.org/viewtopic.php?p=38121#p38121), but I need to find something that's a little easier to edit. If you didn't, it's looking like I might need to do the same steps you took to find the solution.

Comment: @Ellesedil, I'm afraid I didn't notice anything for specifying a global settings file path. If I recall correctly, I had to log on to our build server as the user that executes our SOAP UI tests, open the app, and specify a path. It's less than ideal, obviously.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do some more searching, but I suspect I'm a few hours away from pulling the source down myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by having a different soapui-settings.xml file for each worksapce, then overwriting the SOAPUI_HOME soapui-settings.xml with the appropriate setting file when you startup Soapui.
Create a simple wrapper shell/bat script to do the copying before kicking off soapui.sh, and copy the modified version back if necessary.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't find a sopaui-settings.xml file in my install (Win 7 x64). I also dug around the ProgramData and Appdata folders...

Comment: @Jeremy: My `soapui-settings.xml` file (running Win 7 x64) is in `C:\Users\myusername` - in case it helps anyone who is similarly snagged.